# How to order an array by the name of a referenced table row, rather than it's ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I apologize for any poor terminology I use, as I'm a pretty green (Rails) programmer.  But here is my question:  I'm working on a Rails app (2.3.8) that manages projects.  Every *project* has one *company* (in a separate table) and one *contact* (in a separate table).  I'm currently generating a list of projects which is ordered (1) by *company* and (2) by *contact*.  The problem is that I need that list in alphabetical order (based on the name of the *company/contact*).  As of now, the best I can do is order the list by the *company/contact* ID, which is what the *projects* table is storing.  What are my options—if any?

Here is what my controller currently uses to order the list I need:

```
def jobs_to_be_invoiced
    @to_be_invoiced_prep = Project.prepare_project("To Be Invoiced", "=")   
    @to_be_invoiced = @jobs_to_be_invoiced_prep.all(:order => 'company_id, contact_id')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with, adding one line in your model for Company

```
default_scope order: 'companys.name ASC'
```

Let me know if it works for u.